# Solve system of equations using a "singular" condition

Tags: equation-solving

I want to find a vector $x$ that is orthogonal to some vector $u$. The vector must satisfy the conditions $u\dot x = 0$ and $|x|^2=1$.

Then I pass to *Mathematica* the next code:

```
x = Table[Unique["x"], {2^3}]
Solve[
  x.{0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3], 0} == 0 &&
  Total[Map[#^2 &, x]] == 1, x
]
```

I get the output

```
{
 {x19 -> -x16 - x18, x20 -> -Sqrt[1 - x13^2 - x14^2 - x15^2 - 2 x16^2 - x17^2 - 2 x16 x18 - 2 x18^2]}, 
 {x19 -> -x16 - x18, x20 ->  Sqrt[1 - x13^2 - x14^2 - x15^2 - 2 x16^2 - x17^2 - 2 x16 x18 - 2 x18^2]}
}
```

The "singular" condition that solves my problem is that the argument of `Sqrt` must be zero. I.e., if I try:

```
Solve[1 - x13^2 - x14^2 - x15^2 - 2 x16^2 - x17^2 - 2 x16 x18 - 2 x18^2 == 0, x]
```

I get another solution involving other `Sqrt` term that simplifies my problem:

```
{
 {x17 -> -Sqrt[1 - x13^2 - x14^2 - x15^2 - 2 x16^2 - 2 x16 x18 - 2 x18^2]},
 {x17 ->  Sqrt[1 - x13^2 - x14^2 - x15^2 - 2 x16^2 - 2 x16 x18 - 2 x18^2]}
}
```

And then

```
Solve[1 - x13^2 - x14^2 - x15^2 - 2 x16^2 - 2 x16 x18 - 2 x18^2 == 0, x]
```

And so on, until I get:

```
Solve[1 - 2 x16^2 - 2 x16 x18 - 2 x18^2 == 0, x]
```

that give me the trivial equation for `x16`:

```
{
 {x18 -> 1/2 (-x16 - Sqrt[2 - 3 x16^2])},
 {x18 -> 1/2 (-x16 + Sqrt[2 - 3 x16^2])}
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to automate this?

For example, requiring that only I get one solution, "mathematically", solve this because, this implies that the square root term must be zero. I can tell this to *Mathematica*?

MWE

```
In[23]:= Solve[x.{0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3], 0}==0&&Total[Map[#^2&,x]]==1,x]
During evaluation of In[23]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
Out[23]= {{x9->-x6-x8,x10->-Sqrt[1-x3^2-x4^2-x5^2-2 x6^2-x7^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]},{x9->-x6-x8,x10->Sqrt[1-x3^2-x4^2-x5^2-2 x6^2-x7^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]}}
In[24]:= Solve[1-x3^2-x4^2-x5^2-2 x6^2-x7^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2==0,x]
During evaluation of In[24]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
Out[24]= {{x7->-Sqrt[1-x3^2-x4^2-x5^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]},{x7->Sqrt[1-x3^2-x4^2-x5^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]}}
In[25]:= Solve[1-x3^2-x4^2-x5^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2==0,x]
During evaluation of In[25]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
Out[25]= {{x5->-Sqrt[1-x3^2-x4^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]},{x5->Sqrt[1-x3^2-x4^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]}}
In[26]:= Solve[1-x3^2-x4^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2==0,x]
During evaluation of In[26]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
Out[26]= {{x4->-Sqrt[1-x3^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]},{x4->Sqrt[1-x3^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]}}
In[27]:= Solve[1-x3^2-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2==0,x]
During evaluation of In[27]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
Out[27]= {{x3->-Sqrt[1-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]},{x3->Sqrt[1-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2]}}
In[28]:= Solve[1-2 x6^2-2 x6 x8-2 x8^2==0,x]
During evaluation of In[28]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>
Out[28]= {{x8->1/2 (-x6-Sqrt[2-3 x6^2])},{x8->1/2 (-x6+Sqrt[2-3 x6^2])}}
In[29]:= Solve[2-3 x6^2==0]
Out[29]= {{x6->-Sqrt[(2/3)]},{x6->Sqrt[2/3]}}
```

Comment: In $R^n$ for $n \ge 3$, there is an infinite number of vectors orthogonal to a given vector.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Sure, but using this "algorithm" you can find one.

Comment: Do you care which one you find, or is "any" acceptable?

Comment: `u = {0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3], 0};
x = Array[s, 8];
Solve[x.u == 0 && x.x == 1 && s[8] == 0, x] // FullSimplify`

Comment: @DavidG.Stork In this moment I accept any :).

Comment: `In[251]:= With[{null = 
   First[NullSpace[{{0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3], 
       0}}]]}, null/Norm[null]]

Out[251]= {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1}`

Comment: @Dr.belisarius I try it and doesn't work. I need to use Solve using the argument of the square root to find another equation that also have a square root.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Well, then I need one that use my "procedure". I need find this vector:

Comment: You have not specified the requirement in a way that makes it algorithmic. Frankly I have no idea what the requirements are, other than orthogonality to a given vector and unit length.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Every time I use Solve I get a square root term. Then I use Solve[ArgumentSquareRoot==0,x] that give another square root. Again, I use Solve[ArgumentNewSquareRoot==0,x]. I do this until I get something like `{x8->1/2 (-x6+Sqrt[2-3 x6^2])` The I substitute the solution to the last equation in the equation that get that solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set to zero all variables that correspond to zeros in the fixed vector.

```
vec = {0, 0, 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 0, 1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3], 0};
vars = Array[x, Length[vec]];
zvars = Pick[vars, vec /. { 0 -> True, _?NumericQ :> False}];

Solve[
 Flatten[{vars.vec == 0, Thread[zvars == 0], vars.vars == 1}], vars]

During evaluation of In[302]:= Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables. >>

(* Out[302]= {{x[1] -> 0, x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, 
  x[6] -> 1/2 (-x[4] - Sqrt[2 - 3 x[4]^2]), 
  x[7] -> 1/2 (-x[4] + Sqrt[2 - 3 x[4]^2]), x[8] -> 0}, {x[1] -> 0, 
  x[2] -> 0, x[3] -> 0, x[5] -> 0, 
  x[6] -> 1/2 (-x[4] + Sqrt[2 - 3 x[4]^2]), 
  x[7] -> 1/2 (-x[4] - Sqrt[2 - 3 x[4]^2]), x[8] -> 0}} *)
```

You can avoid `Solve` and stay with linear algebra if you are willing to do some post-processing (I'm not). For this one needs the set of appropriate null vectors that parametrize the viable solutions. I show how to get that much below.

```
zposns = Flatten[Position[vec, 0]];
mat = Prepend[Map[UnitVector[Length[vec], #] &, zposns], vec];
NullSpace[mat]

(* Out[327]= {{0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0}} *)
```

Now there is some more work to combine these into a general solution subject to the norm constraint.